# SQL how to sort column by percentages?

Tags: sql, percentage

Hi I'm trying to sort in sql a column of percentages, but I'm unable to bring '100%' from the bottom to the top result, anyone has a solution to this?

I was using concat(x/y*100,'%') as percentage function, which gave me varying percentages e.g. 50%, 60%, 99%, 100%.

However an order by percentage desc then gives me the following order:
99%
60%
50%
100%

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Add this in your order by clause

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    ...
WHERE   ...
ORDER BY (x/y*100) ASC
```

The reason why `ORDER BY percentage DESC` doesn't work is because `percentage` column is a string and not a numeric.

Comment: @GlennLow can you post the whole query you created?

Comment: @GlennLow because `(x/y*100)` doesn't use index. Can you post your full query? so we can find workaround on it. :)

Comment: Hi John, i'll love to, but there's sensitive information in there so I cant

Comment: my last line of code is basically something like this: order by ((sum(x)-sum(y))/sum(x)) desc. i have omitted the *100, but would it be necessary?

Comment: @GlennLow I understand, if you get rid of `* 100` will it increase the performace?

Comment: sorry for the typo, what I mean was `improve` the performace.

Comment: i think it wouldn't affect the performance much if i'm not mistaken. it'll probably take a short while to compute the function *100. So i've intentionally left it out

Comment: it usually takes about 2-3 minutes to run the query. but this query with the order by has been running for 17 mins now

Comment: the reason is because it doesn't uses index. can you atleast create a dummy copy of your query? :)

Comment: it has something to do with the structure of your tables. proper indexing of the columns will improve the performace of your queries.

Comment: does it work if i substract 1 char from the right of 'margin' and then order by?

Comment: @GlennLow: Did it perform well when you used sorting by your percentage column?

Answer (score 1):

You should be ordering by `x/y`, it will give you the correct sort order. Use your expression that multiplies by `100` and adds a percentage sign to the end to format the output, not for sorting.

Comment: hi can you help me out here too? the query's taking an abysmally long time to run because of the order by x/y desc function