# ORDER BY Percentage - Calculated Within MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql

In a list of records relating to my team's opponents, I want to work out our "bogey teams" – i.e., the teams we lose to the most often. At the moment, I have a query that returns the teams who we have lost to the most. But this does not tell the right story in that, while we have lost to a team 19 times, this is not so bad if we have played them 100 times.

The query I have outputs this with a percentage value (e.g., 19/100 = 19%) – but this is an afterthought in the current way of doing things. I would like the query to actually determine the highest percentage value (I know there is a team we have lost to 81% of the time, but only 16 occasions) and then sort by this.

My current query is this.

```
SELECT re.ID,ce.name,re.opponent,re.bg,re.og,
sum(CASE WHEN re.bg < re.og THEN 1 END) AS defeats, 
count(re.opponent) as played 
FROM resultengine re 
RIGHT JOIN clubengine ce ON re.opponent=ce.ID 
WHERE re.ID < '767700' GROUP BY re.opponent ORDER BY defeats DESC
```

I have checked the following resources but cannot connect the dots:

- [Order a summary result by a percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340674/order-a-summary-result-by-a-percentage)
- [ORDER BY percentage is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777429/order-by-percentage-is-not-working)
- [SQL how to sort column by percentages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791841/sql-how-to-sort-column-by-percentages)

I have attempted a crude way of the (x/y*100) and the concat approach – but I don't know if I'm mis-approaching it. Both instances cause a critical error. Yet, I feel as if it is one of those 'simpler-than-you'd-think-fixes'. Or is it even possible to use the percentage value from a query to actually sort the query?

(This code is an example of the query I am running on the page - if you are wondering why this is $result10 etc.)

Comment: I made it a question for you

Comment: When using `RIGHT JOIN` you shouldn't group by a column in the first table. When there are no matches, that column will be NULL, and you'll group all the null values together.

Comment: The solution in the first question you link to should work. Show how you tried to implement that.

Comment: `100 * SUM(re.bg < re.og) / COUNT(*)  AS defeat_percentage`

Comment: @Barmar, I implemented the solution in the first question much more crudely than the solution, which is doing what I want it to. As a follow-up question to further qualify the output, is it possible within the query to set a min. number of games i.e., five games – because losing one out of one is not as bad as losing 12 out of 16 (if that makes sense)

Comment: You can use `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5` to restrict the results to teams with at least 5 games.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @barmar's comment. The amended query below is now outputting the desired result for me:

```
$query = "SELECT re.ID,ce.name,re.opponent,re.bg,re.og,sum(CASE WHEN re.bg < re.og THEN 1 END) AS defeats, count(re.opponent) as played, 100 * SUM(re.bg < re.og) / COUNT(*)  AS defeat_percentage FROM resultengine re RIGHT JOIN clubengine ce ON re.opponent=ce.ID WHERE re.ID < '767700' GROUP BY re.opponent HAVING COUNT(played) >= 5 ORDER BY defeat_percentage DESC";
```